# What's the idiomatic way to create APIs in Kotlin with async operations?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When creating APIs in Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to handle async actions?

We could create apis that require normal blocking calls, forcing application code to use something like `runBlocking`.

```
////
//// Plain functions 
////

// library code
fun registerHandler(block: (it: Foo) -> String) {
    // save a reference to call when an action happens later
}

// application code
registerHandler {
    runBlocking {
        handleItSuspend(it)
    }
}
```

We could make use of `suspend` more which looks nicer for the application code but requires that we execute our callbacks from suspend functions or coroutine contexts, which may or may not be inconvenient for us.

```
////
//// Suspend functions
////

// library code
fun registerHandler(block: suspend (it: Foo) -> String) {
    // save a reference to call when an action happens later
}

// application code
registerHandler {
    handleItSuspend(it)
}
```

Or we could take functions that return deferred results

```
////
//// Deferred functions
////

// library code
// This handler can be called from anywhere without needing suspend.
fun registerHandler(block: (it: Foo) -> Deferred<String>) {
    // save a reference to call when an action happens later
}

// application code
registerHandler {
    // Function that isn't suspend but returns a deferred
    handleItAsync(it)
}
```

Is there a consensus or an official stance on what we should be doing?

Comment: I'd go with either the second or the third approach. Both are pretty similar, since the `async` method takes a `suspend` block and returns a `Deferred<T>`

Comment: If your library does not handle coroutine execution itself like switching between contexts and dispatchers, I'd expose `suspend fun` so users that are already within coroutines can use it in "blocking" fashion, and an "async" version that calls mentioned `suspend fun` and invokes "callback" block provided by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @msrd0 alluded to in a comment, you can easily convert between arguments for the second and third approaches, so they are equivalent:

```
val block1: suspend (Foo) -> String = ...
val block2: (Foo) -> Deferred<String> = { x -> async { block1(x) } }
val block3: suspend (Foo) -> String = { x -> block2(x).await() }
```

But I'd expect most calls to the `Deferred` version to look like

```
registerHandler { foo -> async { doSomethingSuspend(foo) } }
```

in which case the `suspend` version is easier to use, it will be just

```
registerHandler { foo -> doSomethingSuspend(foo) }
```

Of course, your code base may already use `Deferred` generally enough that this assumption doesn't hold.

> requires that we execute our callbacks from suspend functions or coroutine contexts, which may or may not be inconvenient for us.

I don't think it can be too inconvenient, since it's just a simple `async` (or another coroutine builder) call inside `registerHandler`.

Or did you mean that `registerHandler` needs to be called there? That would only be true if it was *itself* declared `suspend`.

Comment: Thanks for that. For your last comment about the extra async call, you're right about the use case. It would just be an extra async there. Really, I guess the entire question boils down to who has to do the extra async (if at all), the library internally or the application code. Phrased that way, I also think defaulting to suspend makes the most sense.